# how to call my login GSP view before grails index gsp?

Tags: grails, redirect

I m new to grails,can any one help me in getting solution for my below mentioned problem.

I have 2 controllers in my application..now i want to have a login page to it.

I have created login.gsp in my third controller even login action is in same controller.

I have index.gsp in other controller which is my app's welcome page..

grails by default calls to the index.gsp but i want login.gsp

how can i achieve this?

waiting for reply..

With lots of advance thankses

Nandita

Answer (score 4):

### Unsolicited Advice

If you want to add authentication/authorization to your application, I strongly recommend you use one of the existing plugins (e.g. nimble, spring security) rather than writing your own.

### Answer To Your Question

To change the application's start page, simply edit the following rule in `UrlMappings.groovy`

```
"/"(view:"/index")
```

For example, to make `/login.gsp` the start page, change it to:

```
"/"(view:"/login")
```

Or to make it invoke the `index` action of `LoginController` when the application starts, change it to:

```
"/"(controller: 'login', action: 'index')
```

Comment: Thanks..NOw i made my login.gsp as my start page by editing in urlmapping as u told..but i want index page of default controller to display when i login.

Comment: my login.gsp is in other controller..when i click on login it will take me to controller action toIndex.but when i try to render index view or call default controller index action i m getting error.

Comment: how can i call index action of default controller from my generated controller or how can i render index view from my controller

Comment: @Don Quick question, I have changed my start page to be the spring security login like you suggest above by modifying the UrlMappings.groovy. However, when I put in my credentials and press 'Submit' it does the authentication correctly but it sends me back to the login screen again. What do I need to do to send me for example to the index.gsp?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look up the [spring security plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core)

Comment: Thanks i tried with it..but can u please tell me in below syntax what i should write..after installing plug in i need to run the command grails s2-quickstart org.example SecUser SecRole

Comment: i already have 2 domain classes register and address..can u please tell me what exactly i need to do

Comment: I hope you have run s2-quickstart command and created the Role, User and UserRole domains. All you need to do now is assign roles to your users and then secure the controllers / actions.  

For Securing controller do this:

`@Secured(['ROLE_NAME1', 'ROLE_NAME2'])

class DummyContoller{
....}`  

For Securing actions  
  
`class DummyContoller{  

@Secured(['ROLE_NAME1', 'ROLE_NAME2'])  

def edit={  
 }  
}`

Comment: For further details refer http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#23 Tutorials

Comment: thanks.can u answer to my question on Urlmapping which i have posted today.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a authentication plugin like spring security plugin, I recommend to use a filter which checks if the user is logged in and redirects to the login page if not so.

example code:

```
class SecurityFilters {
   def filters = {
       loginCheck(controller:'*', action:'*') {
           before = {
              if(!session.user && !actionName.equals('login')) {
                  redirect(action:'login')
                  return false
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Add this filter to the *grails-app/conf* directory.

More about grails filter http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6 Filters

Comment: thanks.can u answer to my question on Urlmapping which i have posted today.